# Creating 2 records on omniauth-facebook signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I'm using the `omniauth-facebook` gem in combination with `Devise` to enable users to login with their Facebook account. This works fine. The problem now lies in the creation of a new user, when first signing up with Facebook. Each `User` has one `ExtendedProfile` with detailed user info. So the email and password are columns in the `users` table, but location and profile_image are stored in the `extended_profiles` table.

When signing up for the first time, the following method is executed:

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
  end
end
```

Now this creates a record for the `users` table, but not an `extended_profile`. Any idea how I can create a record for `extended_profiles` with the right `user_id` and fill it with the information I get back from Facebook? Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So I've found the solution while trying out house9's answer:

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    user.create_extended_profile(
    :first_name => auth.info.first_name,
    :last_name => auth.info.last_name,
    :facebook_avatar => auth.info.image)
  end
end
```

The `user.create_extended_profile()` line creates a relational record with the auth values filled in! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting it in the block? Not sure if this will work

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    # ....
    user.extended_profile.build
  end
end
```

another option is to put an `after_create` callback on the `User` to create the record

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks

or you can conditionally check if the record exists, change up that code to:

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)
  user = where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first

  unless user
    user = User.new
    user.provider = auth.provider
    # ....
    user.extended_profile.build
    user.save
  end

  user
end
```

Comment: Well I tried your first option, and I got a noMethodError for build because .extended_profile is a nil class at that point. The `after_create` on `User` sounds like a nice solution, but where do I store the auth() values I want to fill the `extended_profile` with in the meantime?

Comment: Can you show your model code and the data attributes you want to store in each?

Comment: I've found a solution! I'll answer my own question with the solution! Thanks for your help, it put me on the right track!